# C# solution using stack

Tags: c#, data-structures, stack

I have a `string s = {abc,def,{pqr, {xyz}}}`. Each `{` should be considered as a level. I need to write a C# solution using stack data structure which will give me the output as:

- abc - Level 1
- def - Level 1
- pqr - Level 2
- xyz - Level 3

I have made a rookies attempt but it is not giving the intended solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "{abc,def,{pqr, {xyz}}}";
        Stack s = new Stack();
        int level = 1;
        bool push = false;

        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (c == '{')
            {
                level++;
                push = true;
            }
            else if (c == '}')
            {
                level--;
                push = false;
            }

            if (push && (c != '{'))
            {
                s.Push(c);
            }
            else if (s.Count >= 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= s.Count; i++)
                    Console.Write(s.Pop());
                Console.WriteLine(level);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never even knew there was a non-generic `Stack` out there...

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use a stack here at all. Just increment the level every time you see `{`, and decrement it every time you see `}`

Comment: Dont have much of a choice, was asked to solve the problem using stack.

Comment: I'm guessing your first problem is not the stack but parsing the string. The second problem: stacks don't have anything on the "same level" unless the contents of the stack is a list, tuple, or other data structure that can hold more than one item.

Comment: What does "using a stack" mean? You could easily have `var stack = new Stack();` and then for each `{` do `stack.Push(null);` (or push whatever, doesn't matter) and for each `}` do `stack.Pop();` and then the current "level" would always be `stack.Count`. Then you'd only have to figure out what's in between and how to split it by comma. -- but is that really what "using stack" meant?

Comment: Does your teacher intend for you to return a stack that has 3 items, two strings (`abc` and `def`) and an inner stack (that itself has two items; a string `pqr` and another innerinner stack, holding just the string `xyz`) ?

Comment: Honestly a stack doesn't make much sense here

Comment: @Jard - Just the output indicated as above but using a stack.